# Iterated matrix multiplication when matrix is defective

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, exponentiation, diagonalization, svd

Is there any easy method of computing

$$A^{n}x$$ when $A$ is not diagonalizeable?

That is, we cannot find $P,D$ such that $A=PDP^{-1}$.

If there is no easy way of computing, can we say anything about the resulting quantity? For instance, convergence to the eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue?

Comment: there is always Jordan form: $A = P J P^{-1},$ where $J = D + N,$ where $D$ is diagonal, $N$ is nilpotent (being strictly triangular) and the most important condition, $DN=ND.$

Comment: What do you mean by 'computing'? A numerical technique?

Answer (score 2):

From the wikipedia page on [spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius), we know that

if $A=VJV^{-1}$ is the Jordan canonical form, where

$$J=\begin{bmatrix}
J_{m_1}(\lambda_1) & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & J_{m_2}(\lambda_2) & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \cdots & \ddots & \cdots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & J_{m_{s-1}}(\lambda_{s-1}) & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & J_{m_s}(\lambda_s)
\end{bmatrix}$$

and $$J_{m_i}(\lambda_i)=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_i & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_i & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda_i & 1 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \lambda_i
\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbf{C}^{m_i \times m_i}, 1\leq i\leq s.$$

Then we have $$A^k=VJ^kV^{-1}$$

and

$$J^k=\begin{bmatrix}
J_{m_1}^k(\lambda_1) & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & J_{m_2}^k(\lambda_2) & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \cdots & \ddots & \cdots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & J_{m_{s-1}}^k(\lambda_{s-1}) & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & J_{m_s}^k(\lambda_s)
\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$J_{m_i}^k(\lambda_i)=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_i^k & {k \choose 1}\lambda_i^{k-1} & {k \choose 2}\lambda_i^{k-2} & \cdots & {k \choose m_i-1}\lambda_i^{k-m_i+1} \\
0 & \lambda_i^k & {k \choose 1}\lambda_i^{k-1} & \cdots & {k \choose m_i-2}\lambda_i^{k-m_i+2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda_i^k & {k \choose 1}\lambda_i^{k-1} \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \lambda_i^k
\end{bmatrix}$$

If the spectral radius is less than $1$, then the quantity converges to zero.

From your description about convergence to the dominant eigenvector, don't forget to normalize your matrix product in every iteration of [power iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration). Even in the case of unique dominant eigenvalue, the convergence is not promised.

Comment: Thanks, are there any more bounds that we can derive? For instance, relating to the condition number, or the *smallest* singular value? In general, it seems incredible that we can only bound certain directions with $A^n x$, and it only depends on the largest singular value!

Comment: Perhaps besides upper bound, consider lower bound as well for the smallest singular value? [inverse iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_iteration) might be of interest to you if you want to use an iterative method to find the other eigenvector.